# How to Deserialize JSON data?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net, json-deserialization

I am new to working with JSON data.

I am reading data from a web service. The query data sent back is the following:

```
[["B02001_001E","NAME","state"],
 ["4712651","Alabama","01"],
 ["691189","Alaska","02"],
 ["6246816","Arizona","04"],
 ["18511620","Florida","12"],
 ["9468815","Georgia","13"],
 ["1333591","Hawaii","15"],
 ["1526797","Idaho","16"],
 ["3762322","Puerto Rico","72"]]
```

Is there a way to Deserialize this data in such a way that the base object will be generated without me first defining what the object is like? In the above example the object is defined by the first row:

```
           ["B02001_001E","NAME","state"],
```

In general the web service will return the query data formatted as a two dimensional JSON array where the first row provides column names and subsequent rows provide data values.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can deserialize this really easily. The data's structure in C# is just `List<string[]>` so you could just do;

```
  List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(jsonString);
```

The above code is assuming you're using json.NET.

EDIT: Note the json is technically an array of string arrays. I prefer to use `List<string[]>` for my own declaration because it's imo more intuitive. It won't cause any problems for json.NET, if you want it to be an array of string arrays then you need to change the type to (I think) `string[][]` but there are some funny little gotcha's with jagged and 2D arrays in C# that I don't really know about so I just don't bother dealing with it here.

Answer (score 35):

If you use .Net 4.5 you can also use standard .Net json serializer:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
...    
Stream jsonSource = ...; // serializer will read data stream
var s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string[][]));
var j = (string[][])s.ReadObject(jsonSource);
```

In .Net 4.5 and older you can use JavaScriptSerializer class:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
...
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string[][] list = serializer.Deserialize<string[][]>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to json.org to find the JSON library for whatever technology you're using to call this web service. Download and link to that library.

Step 2: Let's say you're using Java. You would use JSONArray like this:

```
JSONArray myArray=new JSONArray(queryResponse);
for (int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    JSONArray myInteriorArray=myArray.getJSONArray(i);
    if (i==0) {
        //this is the first one and is special because it holds the name of the query.
    }else{
        //do your stuff
        String stateCode=myInteriorArray.getString(0);
        String stateName=myInteriorArray.getString(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own JSON parser and make it more generic based on your requirement. Here is one which served my purpose nicely, hope will help you too.

```
class JsonParsor
{
    public static DataTable JsonParse(String rawJson)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        Dictionary<string, string> outdict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        StringBuilder keybufferbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder valuebufferbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringReader bufferreader = new StringReader(rawJson);
        int s = 0;
        bool reading = false;
        bool inside_string = false;
        bool reading_value = false;
        bool reading_number = false;
        while (s >= 0)
        {
            s = bufferreader.Read();
            //open JSON
            if (!reading)
            {
                if ((char)s == '{' && !inside_string && !reading)
                {
                    reading = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if ((char)s == '}' && !inside_string && !reading)
                    break;
                if ((char)s == ']' && !inside_string && !reading)
                    continue;
                if ((char)s == ',')
                    continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (reading_value)
                {
                    if (!inside_string && (char)s >= '0' && (char)s <= '9')
                    {
                        reading_number = true;
                        valuebufferbuilder.Append((char)s);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                //if we find a quote and we are not yet inside a string, advance and get inside
                if (!inside_string)
                {
                    if ((char)s == '\"' && !inside_string)
                        inside_string = true;
                    if ((char)s == '[' && !inside_string)
                    {
                        keybufferbuilder.Length = 0;
                        valuebufferbuilder.Length = 0;
                                reading = false;
                                inside_string = false;
                                reading_value = false;
                    }
                    if ((char)s == ',' && !inside_string && reading_number)
                    {
                        if (!dataTable.Columns.Contains(keybufferbuilder.ToString()))
                            dataTable.Columns.Add(keybufferbuilder.ToString(), typeof(string));
                        if (!outdict.ContainsKey(keybufferbuilder.ToString()))
                            outdict.Add(keybufferbuilder.ToString(), valuebufferbuilder.ToString());
                        keybufferbuilder.Length = 0;
                        valuebufferbuilder.Length = 0;
                        reading_value = false;
                        reading_number = false;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                //if we reach end of the string
                if (inside_string)
                {
                    if ((char)s == '\"')
                    {
                        inside_string = false;
                        s = bufferreader.Read();
                        if ((char)s == ':')
                        {
                            reading_value = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (reading_value && (char)s == ',')
                        {
                            //put the key-value pair into dictionary
                            if(!dataTable.Columns.Contains(keybufferbuilder.ToString()))
                                dataTable.Columns.Add(keybufferbuilder.ToString(),typeof(string));
                            if (!outdict.ContainsKey(keybufferbuilder.ToString()))
                            outdict.Add(keybufferbuilder.ToString(), valuebufferbuilder.ToString());
                            keybufferbuilder.Length = 0;
                            valuebufferbuilder.Length = 0;
                            reading_value = false;
                        }
                        if (reading_value && (char)s == '}')
                        {
                            if (!dataTable.Columns.Contains(keybufferbuilder.ToString()))
                                dataTable.Columns.Add(keybufferbuilder.ToString(), typeof(string));
                            if (!outdict.ContainsKey(keybufferbuilder.ToString()))
                                outdict.Add(keybufferbuilder.ToString(), valuebufferbuilder.ToString());
                            ICollection key = outdict.Keys;
                            DataRow newrow = dataTable.NewRow();
                            foreach (string k_loopVariable in key)
                            {
                                CommonModule.LogTheMessage(outdict[k_loopVariable],"","","");
                                newrow[k_loopVariable] = outdict[k_loopVariable];
                            }
                            dataTable.Rows.Add(newrow);
                            CommonModule.LogTheMessage(dataTable.Rows.Count.ToString(), "", "row_count", "");
                            outdict.Clear();
                            keybufferbuilder.Length=0;
                            valuebufferbuilder.Length=0;
                            reading_value = false;
                            reading = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (reading_value)
                        {
                            valuebufferbuilder.Append((char)s);
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            keybufferbuilder.Append((char)s);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    switch ((char)s)
                    {
                        case ':':
                            reading_value = true;
                            break;
                        default:
                            if (reading_value)
                            {
                                valuebufferbuilder.Append((char)s);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                keybufferbuilder.Append((char)s);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```