# Is it possible to get a value out of a literal string in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a literal string that contains details of a json array that i need to extract a value from in C#

The string looks like the following:

```
"{\"Field1\":[],\"Field2\":333,\"Field3\":\"string\"....
```

Now Field2 is the field i wish to get in this isntance, but i have no idea how to in C#

Comment: you may want to `Split` the string using `string.Split` first. then to get the value, simply use index [1] of the result

Comment: Does `field2` always contains just one value?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `Newtonsoft.Json` package on nuget.org, it can parse the JSON for you and then you can retrieve the keys by name

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11044010)

Comment: @VadimMartynov Funny, using this package is exactly how I and many other developers perform the exact task described in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value is in JSON format, use [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize it to form a C# type then you can read the value as you read any other property in a class

Comment: Or just use LINQ to JSON - no need to model this as a class in C# unless it's useful for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (apart from using external packages/addons whatever) would be writing a small regex-function like this:

```
public string GetField(string fieldName)
{
    Regex rgxGetField = new Regex(fieldName + "\\\":(.*?),");
    Match mGetField = rgxGetField(jString);
    return = mGetField.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

For sure only works for the format you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to deserialize the JSON string. See [How to Deserialize JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242429/how-to-deserialize-json-data) for a number of excellent answers.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help

i ended up using the following:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(string);
field2= d.field2;
```