# How to parse This JSON in Windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone

Please help me parse this JSON  using JSON.net in c#
[JSON DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj0Ka.png)

Here is Result

```
[{"rescode":0,"policyid":"1","Insuredid":"2606"},
{"rescode":0,"policyid":"2","Insuredid":"2607"},
{"rescode":0,"policyid":"3","Insuredid":"2608"}]
```

Comment: That JSON is invalid.  Try uploading it to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will get errors.  Likely it's supposed to represent an array so should have outer brackets: `[ {...}, {...} ]`.  You'll need to fix your JSON before you can deserialize with a JSON serializer.  Also, what JSON serializer are you trying to use?  [tag:json.net]?  Have you looked at [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105) and [How to Deserialize JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242429)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public class Product {

    public int Rescode {get;set;}
    public int Policyid {get;set;}
    public int InsuredId {get;set;}

}
Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```