# MVC C# read value from cookie created by jQuery and JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, cookies

I have a cookie that is saved via jQuery plugin on which the value is JSON.stringified object.

I need to read and decode this cookie in C#. Although I have successfully read the cookie, I had no success on converting it to an object.

Any clue is greatly appreciated

Comment: There are already many questions about how to deserialize JSON in c#, for instance [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105), or [How to Deserialize JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242429) or [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165), or [deserializing JSON to .net object using NewtonSoft (or linq to json maybe?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639).  Please be more specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A fun way to do it is via dynamic `dynamic person = Json.Decode(jsonString);`

you will be blind ind the intellisesne way, but aslong as you knwo the structure then you can just dot your way around like this

```
dynamic person = Json.Decode(jsonString);
string firstname = person.Firstname;
int age = person.Age;
//etc.
```

There is alot of libraries Newtonsoft's Json.NET or System.Web.Helpers are tho good ones.

Json.NET syntax is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString)`

System.Web.Helpers syntax is as mentioned `Json.Decode(jsonString)`

and if you have the model for the recieving object then jsut add it to the generic like this

```
Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<YorObjectClass>(jsonString)
```

see details about [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)