# How to deserialize the above JSON string to datatable in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I deserialize the following JSON string to a datatable in c#

```
{
  "m_MaxCapacity":2147483647,
  "Capacity":1888,
  "m_StringValue":"<table border=3><tr><th>Master ID</th><th>Tag ID</th><th>Plant ID</th><th>Machine Name</th><th>Sap ID</th><th>Log</th></tr><tr><td>2296</td><td>567</td><td>567</td><td>hjhnh</td><td>567</td><td>17-09-2016 15:03:04</td></tr><tr><td>2297</td><td>55555</td><td>567</td><td>hjhnh</td><td>567</td><td>17-09-2016 15:04:27</td></tr><tr><td>2298</td><td>55555</td><td>567</td><td>hjhnh</td><td>0000</td><td>17-09-2016 15:04:53</td></tr><tr><td>2299</td><td>55555</td><td>567</td><td>hjhnh</td><td>0000</td><td>17-09-2016 15:05:11</td></tr><tr><td>2300</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>nnn</td><td>789</td><td>17-09-2016 15:20:51</td></tr><tr><td>2301</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>AF</td><td>789</td><td>17-09-2016 15:23:57</td></tr><tr><td>2302</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ttttttt</td><td>789</td><td>17-09-2016 15:33:22</td></tr><tr><td>2303</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ttttttt</td><td>789</td><td>17-09-2016 15:43:10</td></tr><tr><td>2304</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ttttttt</td><td>789</td><td>17-09-2016 15:43:23</td></tr><tr><td>2305</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ttttttt</td><td>789</td><td>17-09-2016 15:43:50</td></tr><tr><td>2306</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>lmno</td><td>789</td><td>17-09-2016 15:49:25</td></tr><tr><td>2307</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ttttttt</td><td>789</td><td>22-09-2016 11:23:16</td></tr><tr><td>2308</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ttttttt</td><td>789</td><td>22-09-2016 11:40:07</td></tr><tr><td>2309</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ccccc</td><td>789</td><td>22-09-2016 11:40:18</td></tr><tr><td>2310</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ttttttt</td><td>789</td><td>22-09-2016 11:45:53</td></tr><tr><td>2311</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>ttttttt</td><td>789</td><td>22-09-2016 12:00:48</td></tr><tr><td>2312</td><td>6678</td><td>6754</td><td>mmmmmmmmmm</td><td>789</td><td>22-09-2016 12:00:52</td></tr></table>",
  "m_currentThread":0
}
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: What have you tried? You know that the process is `deserializing`, have you researched anything at all or are you looking for someone to provide a copy + paste answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize JSON data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242429/how-to-deserialize-json-data)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add package `Newtonsoft.Json` to your project.Next create class with object. You can use http://json2csharp.com/ it's very helpfull tool. Finally you have to `Deserialize` yours json. Try use this sample.

```
 public class RootObject
    {
        public long m_MaxCapacity { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
        public string m_StringValue { get; set; }
        public int m_currentThread { get; set; }
    }

string json=   {"m_MaxCapacity":2147483647,"Capacity":1888,"m_StringValue":"Master IDTag IDPlant IDMachine NameSap IDLog2296567567hjhnh56717-09-2016 15:03:04229755555567hjhnh56717-09-2016 15:04:27229855555567hjhnh000017-09-2016 15:04:53229955555567hjhnh000017-09-2016 15:05:11230066786754nnn78917-09-2016 15:20:51230166786754AF78917-09-2016 15:23:57230266786754ttttttt78917-09-2016 15:33:22230366786754ttttttt78917-09-2016 15:43:10230466786754ttttttt78917-09-2016 15:43:23230566786754ttttttt78917-09-2016 15:43:50230666786754lmno78917-09-2016 15:49:25230766786754ttttttt78922-09-2016 11:23:16230866786754ttttttt78922-09-2016 11:40:07230966786754ccccc78922-09-2016 11:40:18231066786754ttttttt78922-09-2016 11:45:53231166786754ttttttt78922-09-2016 12:00:48231266786754mmmmmmmmmm78922-09-2016 12:00:52","m_currentThread":0}

List<RootObject> list = new List<RootObject>();

list= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use: http://json2csharp.com/

there you get the class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public long m_MaxCapacity { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public string m_StringValue { get; set; }
    public int m_currentThread { get; set; }
}
```

then you can add it to your context.