# Deserialize JSON - How can I deserialize this JSON?

Tags: c#, json

Json looks like:

```
 [{"id":"001788fffe2e6479","internalipaddress":"192.168.1.2"}]
```

My C# code for deserialize (using Newtonsoft):

```
        public class ipBridge
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string InternalIpAddress { get; set; }
        public string MacAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocatedBridge
    {
        public string BridgeId { get; set; }
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

and:

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.test.com/api"); 

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


        ipBridge[] responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ipBridge[]>(responseString); //responseString = [{"id":"001788fffe2e6479","internalipaddress":"192.168.1.2"}]

        responseModel.Select(x => new LocatedBridge() { BridgeId = x.Id, IpAddress = x.InternalIpAddress }).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine($"{ip}"); // ip = internalipaddress of JSON, HOW?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242429/how-to-deserialize-json-data)

Comment: use visual studio to automatically create the class for you. add the json into your clipboard and insert it with vs as a new class

Comment: I'm mean it's bad but you could use `ipBridge[i].InternalIpAddress `

Comment: also, your line where you use `Select()` is used wrong. you don't save the list anywhere. it returns a new list but you through it away. Your code is all wrong

Answer (score 1):

You have working deserialization code and question is actually not related with it. What you want is to access your deserialized object field.

```
ipBridge[] responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ipBridge[]>(responseString); 
var locatedBridgeModel = responseModel.Select(x => new LocatedBridge() { BridgeId = x.Id, IpAddress = x.InternalIpAddress }).ToList();

Console.WriteLine($"{responseModel[0].InternalIpAddress}"); 
//or
Console.WriteLine($"{locatedBridgeModel[0].IpAddress}"); 
//or
Console.WriteLine($"{locatedBridgeModel.First().IpAddress}");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `ipBridge` objects in your JSON (based on names used in JSON), from occurence of `[`, `]` (square brackets) I can tell that it should be a list of those objects. Thus, it should be deserialized to `List<ipBridge>`.

Use this code:

```
var json = @"[{ ""id"":""001788fffe2e6479"",""internalipaddress"":""192.168.1.2""}]";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ipBridge>>(json);
```